# webViewDidFinishLoad is not fired when I use goBack

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I want to do some extra work after the webpage is loaded, so I add some code in webViewDidFinished, but it seems in this situation it's not working.

Situation:I visit a web page with UIWebview then click a link to another, after that, I run

```
[webview goback];
```

It seems the page was loaded from cache, only

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

is called,

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
```

is not called.

Comment: have you added UIWebViewDelegate in .h file and binded your web view with File's owner?

Comment: on, @ShahPaneri must I? the function runs except this situation.

Comment: @ShahPaneri added it. It didn't work.

Comment: `- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"finish loding..");
}` Please log something in this method.So u can be more specific about this method is called or not. :)

Comment: @ShahPaneri Actually I did do some log and also I set a breakpoint there to check it...

Comment: i have put one back button and on the click of that i have called `[webview goback];` and in my app i have used -`(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{ NSLog(@"load start...");}` and `- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView { NSLog(@"finish loding..");}`.My both methods are working while clicking on back.!!

Comment: @ShahPaneri try http://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.10.1.kEUNrf&id=19955188752&ad_id=&am_id=&cm_id=&pm_id= to another link and then back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However quirky, I suspect that this is correct behaviour. From the Apple doc:

> webViewDidFinishLoad:
>
> Sent after a web view finishes loading a frame.

My bet is that the UIWebView caches a certain number of pages, and the `goBack` and `goForward` methods do not guarantee that locations stored in the back-forward list are reloaded. And thus does not fire `webViewDidFinishLoad`.

But even though this is might be correct behaviour, I would certainly agree that this is bad API design. There should definitely be a `finishLoad`-ish method to hook into for back/forward/in-page navigation.

Comment: It seems a reasonable answer.

Comment: @rivera I've been told that the line between an excuse and an explanation is also a thin one :-)

Answer (score 5):

True. There's still a way to get informed about a change to the history stack:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(webViewHistoryDidChange:)
                                             name:@"WebHistoryItemChangedNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

Since `UIWebView` is not KVO compliant on `canGoBack` this seems to be the only way to enable/disable a potential back button.

Comment: Xcode errors out stating it cannot find WebHistoryItemChangedNotification. I did add import WebKit to my uiwebView controller . Any thoughts?

Comment: @shrutim: This is a hack which listens to a private notification. Therefore you need to subscribe to the `@"WebHistoryItemChangedNotification"` as a string, not as a symbol.

Comment: erm doesn't seem to be firing for me. Does anyone know if this is for UIWebView only or whether it works for WKWebKit also (which I'm using).